# How to center big size div in a small div with scroll bar

Tags: css, angular

[image]I am trying do center a big div inside in a small div. the small div has property overflow: auto. The inside big div also can change its size by zooming.

Problem:
when the inside div is smaller than outside div, it can be centered. but if the size is bigger, it failed.

I need to change width and height of containment. it possible bigger or smaller than the edit.

on the following pic demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. The black square is the outside div. the red square is the div should be alway in center(it can be bigger than black box or smaller than black box). The size is changed by code. In order to view all the content of the red box, the black box should have scrollbars. The problem is when the red box is bigger than black, I can not set the red box in the center. It always increase to bottom and right.

the link likes :

http://jsfiddle.net/0rLjnew3/1/

Anyone have the solution?

```
<div id="edit">
<div id="containment"></div>
</div>

.containment 
{
    width:1500px; height:1500px;
    position : absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

thanks

Comment: the link should be http://jsfiddle.net/uh3r54wb/

Comment: Can you draw what are you trying to achieve? How can you tell that "inner" div (`containment`) is not centered in your second example? If you zoom out you can see it is perfectly centered....

Comment: Does this achieve what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/8ryw5hdp/3/

Comment: @Halden Because I need to scale the size of containment, I have to add scrollbar to edit. so if the containment size is smaller than edit, the scrollbar should dispear, otherwise the scrollbar should show, and the containment should be always in the center of edit.

Comment: Ok, how's this: http://jsfiddle.net/0xpzryc8/

Comment: @halden, Thanks. The horizonal and vertical scrollbar are default on left and top. What I want to achieve is they are in the center positon. I have edited my question with a pic.

Comment: The `containment` is actually centered, use inspect element to view it. So centering the scrollbars would actually make the `div` be `75%` top and left.

Comment: @halden, Is there a way to center scroll bar, which means always center content of containment? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `overflow: auto`, because if will most likely do a scroll.

Use `overflow: visible` instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using flexbox to center? That way, you don't need to use **position: absolute**, and it will always be centered corretcly.

```css
#edit{
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 100vh;
  }
#containment{
    width:1500px; height:1500px; opacity:0.5;  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="edit">
  <div id="containment"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: it does not center the containment. The scroll bar still default to the top position.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

I'm not sure if this is quite the correct solution, but it will center the scrollbars as per your request.
In order to do this you will either need to use `JavaScript` or in my case, `jQuery`.

Read more about how to utilise and load jQuery into your own project [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).

Once you have this in your project, add this bit of code:

```
$("#edit").scrollTop(($("#containment").height() - $("#edit").height())/4);
$("#edit").scrollLeft(($("#containment").width() - $("#edit").width())/4);
```